# Primitive type in JPA mapping. What if the database column may be NULL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, primitive

Given this class mapped with JPA (using JPA 1.0 and Hibernate):

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    private int bar;

    /* ... */
}
```

1. What happens if I try to load a record which has the `BAR` column set to NULL?
2. Can I specify how to set the `bar` field when the corresponding column is NULL?

*Notes*

I know this is not a best practice. The question is more out of curiosity and it is inspired by this situation:

- The database table is a staging table: adding a `NOT NULL` constraint is impractical. Bad data is expected, and the point of my code is to validate, clean up and/or reject data before loading it into the "real" database.
- I have acceptable default values for some fields. For example, a `boolean` flag which should default to `false`.

Comment: If the db column can contain null you really should use a wrapper class to represent the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Exception

2.

```
@Column(name = “bar”, nullable = false, columnDefinition = “bigint(20) default 0″)
private int bar;
```

it solves your problem.

Comment: But with point 2 I need to change the database column definition, don't I?

Comment: I agree that if you really want a Null representation you should just change bar to Integer. But if you want to avoid null, you can set a default value.

Comment: By the way, I think primitive types already have a default value. But if you already have a column with null entries, change bar to Integer is the solution.

Answer (score 13):

I would rather use objects if a column may contain null value because Matheus's idea introduces false data. `NULL <> 0`!

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by false data here. Matheus's is setting the default to 0 and nullable = false, so it would never be null. what do you mean by bad/false data?

Comment: `columnDefinition` is used *only* for DDL generation (i.e. generating statements to create and alter tables), so the default value will be the default value of the primitive. In fact, you shouldn't create columns with default values when you use JPA. If your field is a primitive, it will default to the primitive type's default value. If your field is an object, the database will set the default value as defined in your table, but the column's counterpart in the inserted entity object won't be updated to reflect the default value.